# Why is so much attention given to unit testing (TDD) and so little to component level testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-tests

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulperez/2010/04/29/unit-testing-component-level-testing-and-ui-testing-what-to-use-and-when/) great articles explains the difference between unit testing, component level testing and UI testing. At all my previous companies great deal of attention was given to unit testing and less to automated UI testing (end-to-end integration tests). I've never seen component testing practiced in these companies.

It's interesting because as I see it in large applications it's the component testing that helps most during architecture refactoring or ensures against defects by novice developers.  Yet, there's almost no information on the web on this subject, almost no books on amazon, while there's a ton of information both on unit testing and automated UI test. Why is it so?

Comment: care to expain why downvote?

Comment: You're probably looking for the wrong thing.  Try searching for ["integration testing."](https://www.google.com/search?q=integration+testing)

Comment: I agree to Robert. Your assumption is wrong. There are tons of information about this topic, you just have to use the right keywords to search for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, if I search for `integration tests`, there's a bunch of information of end-to-end tests including UI. As I understand `component level testing` is not end-to-end. Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you consider a "component?"  Integration testing means "how do these classes or modules work together?"  It doesn't necessarily have to be end-to-end.

Comment: @RobertHarvey,  let's assume that a component is a class. And component level testing tests interaction of multiple classes as opposed to TDD which limits testing to one class and stubs dependent classes

Comment: I also agree with Robert. Having just read the linked article, the term I would use (for the concept the author calls "component tests") is "integration tests". And people talk about integration tests all the time, especially as compared to "unit tests".

Comment: @EricKing, yes, but they also usually associate them with UI or end-to-end testing. Hard to differentiate :(

Comment: @RobertHarvey, [here](http://qa-matters.com/2014/12/28/layers-of-test-automation/) is also the article which splits `integration testing` into two sub-categories: `Integration tests at the code component level` and `Integration tests at the system component level`. I guess I was talking about the first sub category in my question

Comment: OK.  So what is it that you are looking for specifically?  Now that you have the correct terms, what is it that you actually need to know?

Comment: "TDD which limits testing to one class and stubs dependent classes" [citation needed].  TDD as a process is actually agnostic about the degree to which you should isolate and stub dependencies; note that many well-known advocates of TDD suggest not using stubs in many situations, see e.g. https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/mockists-are-dead-long-live-classicists and http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/11/tdd-tests-are-not-unit-tests

Comment: @Maximus: This article uses "component level testing" in a way that will confuse almost everyone. After reading this article, let me rephrase what precisely that article means by component level testing: **"automated testing of an UI application by calling into the UI automation and API hooks built into the UI application."** If you take away any one word from this definition, or if you define "component level testing" any other way, then this is a question that is unrelated to that linked article. The UI automation hooks is the hardest part; most UI applications are developed without it.

Answer (score 14):

The terms “unit testing” and “component testing” are not defined universally, and different people hold different notions what these terms mean precisely. However, they are generally understood to be **the same thing**. The ISTQB (a testing qualification organization) does not seem to differentiate between these terms, preferring “component tests” in their literature.

The ISTQB sees the following major testing levels:

- Acceptance tests, which are performed by the customer.
- System tests, which verify requirements on the complete system
- Integration tests, which cover the interaction of components.
- Component tests, which test components in isolation. Unit tests are component tests.

The article you quoted draws a line at the level of granularity: according to the author, the test subject of unit tests would be single methods, whereas component tests would cover whole modules. Also, the focus would move from verification of the component's contract to validation in the context of the application/whole system. **These differences found by that article are not universally recognized**. How large the “unit” of an unit test is depends. Often, the unit is a whole class.

Other sources see the difference in the role which performs the tests: whereas unit tests would be performed by developers, component tests and integration tests would be performed by dedicated testers. Again, this difference is not universally recognized. In practice, integration tests always require the assistance of developers, so that test drivers and test stubs can be created to stand in for missing components.

Comment: So the conclusion is that no one knows with certainty what unit tests or component testes are?

Comment: The conclusion is that you don't need precise definitions for those words in order to fully understand how to test a system.

Comment: Another conclusion is that using those terms is meaningless, unless you define them.

Comment: Yet another conclusion is that a mature reader should understand that different authors writing at different times will use different words to say the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that part of the problem is that people seem to disagree on what to call different 'levels' of testing and so this complicates matters a bit. The other point I think should be made is that giving advice on unit testing (by which I mean individual functions) or UI testing is much easier to do.

There are some people who dislike 'mid' level tests ([Integrated Tests Are A Scam](https://vimeo.com/80533536)).